# Using variables in parameters through sending post data via ajax request

Tags: javascript, http-post

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to send a variable through the parameters through post data via an ajax request, I cannot get it to work for some odd reason. When I use what the actual variable contains, there is no problem, but I cannot do that since it changes every time, so instead of using something hard-coded I wanted to try using a variable, the charset of the characters it contains is always the same though.

```
var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
uri='http://www.example.com/profile.php';
http.open('POST',uri,true);
params='name=Tom&lastname=Jordan&'+variable+'='+secondvariable+';
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
http.setRequestHeader('Content-length',params.length);
http.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
http.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(http.readyState==4&&http.status==200){
//alert(http.responseText);
}
};
http.send(params);
```

What is the correct syntax to include a variable alongside with some plain-text? Or simply how can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a stray quote:

Change:

```
params='name=Tom&lastname=Jordan&'+variable+'='+secondvariable+';
```

to:

```
params='name=Tom&lastname=Jordan&'+variable+'='+secondvariable;
```

Also, make sure to *escape* your variables properly:

```
params='name=Tom&lastname=Jordan&'+variable+'='+encodeURIComponent(secondvariable);
```

Comment: Ok i'll give it a try right now and tell you if i have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra single-quote:

```
params='name=Tom&lastname=Jordan&'+variable+'='+secondvariable+';
```

The `+'` at the end isn't necessary, and it's treating the semi-colon as a string.  (Probably resulting in a syntax error.)